# Cast everything for 2 decimal points?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to divide two integers: 8/15 and return "53.33".

I've tried every single combination, and I've found that this is the only way I can return the desired value:

`select cast(100*cast(8/cast(15 as decimal(10,4)) as decimal(18,4)) as decimal(18,2))`

Is there a shorter way?

Thanks.

Comment: `CAST(8*1.0/15 AS DECIMAL(10,2))`?

Comment: Just need to multiple that * 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing interger division. Use float, and multiply by 100.

```
select 8/15.00 * 100
```

Or, for your precision, just do the cast **once**

```
select cast(8/15.00 * 100 as decimal (10,2))
```

If these are integers in a table then multiple by 1.0 and cast **once**

**DEMO**

```
declare @table table (int_one int, int_two int)
insert into @table 
values
(8,15)

select 
    cast(((int_one * 1.0) / int_two) * 100 as decimal(10,2))
from @table
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't have "15.00", I have "15". So I would need to cast the denominator and the result.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select (cast (8 as money)/cast(15 as money) * 100)
```